# Auto-populating To,CC,BCC fields in Outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to populate an email distribution list from a list in column "B" based on its condition in one cell over in cell "A"

Private Sub Outlook_Email()

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim emailTo As String
Dim emailCC As String
Dim emailBCC As String

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If olApp Is Nothing Then
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

emailTo = "To"
emailCC = "CC"
emailBCC = "BCC"

For Each cell In Range("B2:B100")
    If cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "To" Then emailTo = emailTo & cell.Value & ", "
    ElseIf cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "CC" Then emailCC = emailCC & cell.Value & ", "
    Else cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "BCC" Then emailBCC = emailBCC & cell.Value & ", "
    End If
Next

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
    .To = emailTo
    .cc = emailCC
    .bcc = emailBCC
    .Display
End With
```

End Sub

---

The error message I am getting is: Compile Error, Else without If at the CC line in the loop.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The construction of the strings looks a bit malformed. Try something closer to this.

```
emailTo = vbNullString
emailCC = vbNullString
emailBCC = vbNullString

For Each cell In Range("B2:B100")
    Select Case LCase(cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value)
        Case "to"
            emailTo = emailTo & cell.Value & "; "
        Case "bcc"
            emailBCC = emailBCC & cell.Value & "; "
        Case "cc"
            emailCC = emailCC & cell.Value & "; "
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
Next
```

Note the semi-colon used as an email address separator.

Answer (score 0):

`If` statements written on one line are treated as a closed if block:

```
If cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "To" Then emailTo = emailTo & cell.Value & ", "
```

If you want to expand that If block with Elses, you need a line break:

```
If cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "To" Then 
   emailTo = emailTo & cell.Value & ", "
Else...
```